# Latest update to UBUNTU 19.10 causes files from Google Drive to open as Read-Only

Tags: drive, google, read-only

One of the updates this past week, April 13-17, 2020, caused my Google drive to mount my files as "READ-ONLY". I'm currently using Ubuntu 19.10 as my primary desktop. I have Ubuntu 20.04 BETA installed as a VM, and it mounts Google Drive correctly. I can read and write files directly through 20.04. In 19.10 I can write/delete directories, write/delete files, but can only open files in read-only.